# How can I share string-array between applications in Android?

Tags: android, resources, share, arrays

My main idea is to share resources between two applications.
I'm using code below to get string item, but when I'm doing the same with string-array, it returns 0 always(it couldn't find resource):

```
String packageName = "com.example.mymainapp.mymodule.app.libs";
Resources res = getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(packageName);
int resourceId = res.getIdentifier(packageName + ":string/items", null, null);
```

I also tryed to do:

```
int resourceId = res.getIdentifier(packageName + ":array/items", null, null);
```

and

```
int resourceId = res.getIdentifier(packageName + ":string/items", "array", null);
```

and

```
int resourceId = res.getIdentifier("items", "array", null);
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: did you try `int resourceId = res.getIdentifier("items", "array", packageName);` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. But still returns 0.

Comment: and the application identified by this package is installed ?

Comment: Yes, sure, I already retrieved simple string resource from it.

Comment: can you post the relevant part of the array xml declaration?

Comment: There is no need in that, I did that trick, I was right in my first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right variant, I was wrong some time before when got result from resId:

```
int resId = res.getIdentifier(packageName + ":array/items", null, null);
```